# Python Assistance with a small code

Tags: python, excel

How to remove duplicates from an Excel Spreadsheet using Python then removing it from one cloumn next. So I was able to remove duplicates from the sheet but i want to go even further to remove duplicates from one column. There are data in each row and column but the columns can have duplicate names. I want to be able to keep the data that was in the row just not have all the same names associated with each row. The code below is what I have found and used.

```
import csv

print "Please enter file name you want to review"
file = raw_input("> ")

read1 = open(file, "rb")
reader = csv.reader(set(read1))
newfile = raw_input("Please enter the new file name! ")
read2 = open(newfile, "wb")
writing = csv.writer(read2)

for row in reader:
    writing.writerow(row)

read1.close()
read2.close()
```

Comment: Please provide a short example with before and after data, just needs a few rows to illustrate what you are hoping to accomplish.

Comment: computer logonname path of file result ip mac
tom bla felix complete 202.21.21.1 random
tom bla feeling complete 202.21.21.1 random
tom bla Really complete 202.21.21.1 random
tommy bla when complete 98.21.45.24 the
tommy bla brown talk to someone 98.21.45.24 the
sam bla system talk to someone 34.12.11.21 realing
sammy bla fire talk to someone 45.12.54.22 realing2
Adrian bla to home talk to someone 8.2.33.2 realing3

Comment: Try editing your question with that info so we can see the formatting, hard to tell what is going on in a comment.

Comment: Sorry I am still trying to get the format so I could put it in there. Everytime I try it bundles it up like above